# JQuery .on("click", functionName) not running

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 2 functions and 2 button. My buttons will not trigger my onClick event. Both the functions work when testing in chrome developer console but i cannot seem to assign them to my buttons.

```js
function move_up() {
  /get current page data
var cur_page_num = $('#current_page').data("page")
//increment to new page
var new_page_num = parseInt(cur_page_num) + 1
//change current page data to new page
$('#current_page').data('page', `${new_page_num}`)
console.log(`moving to ${new_page_num} from ${cur_page_num}`)
  //move cur page up then move new page left
  $(`#page_${cur_page_num}`).animate({
    bottom: "110vh"
  }, 500, function() {
    $(`#page_${new_page_num}`).animate({
      left: "0"
    }, 500)
  });

}

function move_down() {
  //get current page data
var cur_page_num = $('#current_page').data("page")
//increment to new page
var new_page_num = parseInt(cur_page_num) - 1
//change current page data to new page
$('#current_page').data('page', `${new_page_num}`)
console.log(`moving to ${new_page_num} from ${cur_page_num}`)
  //move cur page up then move new page left
  $(`#page_${cur_page_num}`).animate({
    left: "150vh"
  }, 500, function() {
    $(`#page_${new_page_num}`).animate({
      bottom: "0"
    }, 500)
  });

}
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready")
  $('#pageRight').on("click", move_up)
  $('#pageLeft').on("click", move_down)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="current_page" data-page="1"></span>
<button class="pageChanger" id="pageLeft"><</button>
<button class="pageChanger" id="pageRight">></button>
```

i've tried `.click` instead of `.on`. I've also tried simple adding the onClick attribute to each button but that also had no results. My script is linked at the very end of my HTML document after JQuery and both buttons. Whats the problem here? i can add more of my code if needed but its not that complicated right now.

Comment: Are you sure `cur_page_num` and `new_page_num` are set correctly? Can you add the HTML for the element being animated and the code that sets this variable?

Comment: @HarryWhitnear Is there a `form` inside your HTML? Since neither button is marked as `type="button"` they may be causing a postback to the server in which case you wouldn't see anything happen in your script. I tested your example in a code snippet and declared `cur_page_num` and `new_page_num` above the function declarations and `document.ready` and both callbacks fired on clicking the buttons.

Comment: I've added the rest of the JS file. I'm just trying to swap between ```<div class="page" id="page_1">``` to ```<div class="page" id="page_2">```. when i run in chrome developer console the fucntion ```move_up()``` it works as intended and moves to page 2 and vice versa

Comment: Code snippet is throwing an error: `"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:` on  Chrome: Version 88.0.4324.182 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I dont have any forms. i placed the 2 buttons near the top of my HTML at the top of the body and before my pages. i can run the functions and they both seem to work i just cant get them to run onClick

Comment: Are you sure adding jQuery is successful? Have you checked your console for any error messages?

Comment: console returns no errors. im using the console to run the functions. my console.log() is showing up. the pages are moving as intended

Comment: Can you add your HTML? `var cur_page_num = $('#current_page').data("page")` may be getting NaN. Script seems fine with `var cur_page_num = 1"

Comment: the page data is from the span above it. that's just where im storing my current page. ive added that to my posted code now. we start at default 1. as i said my ```console.log(`moving to ${new_page_num} from ${cur_page_num}`)``` is shown in my log when moving aswell as the pages actually moving i type ```move_up()``` in my console and it returns ```moving to page 2 from 1```

Comment: your code is working properly in my machine but i have to comment 1st line of move_up() function // /get current page data

Comment: https://github.com/HPWhitnear/hpwhitnear.github.io i've uploaded my full current code here. having trouble formatting properly on here

Comment: and you can run it at https://hpwhitnear.github.io/ on here the buttons do nothing but typing ```move_up()``` in the console will. i was trying to avoid doxing myself but im desperate now lol

Comment: It's a CSS z-index problem, see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a z-index problem. Your `.pageChanger` class is using `position: fixed` and other elements are essentially making it unclickable by being higher in the hierarchy. Update

```
.pageChanger {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

to make the click listeners clickable.

Answer (score -1):

Try using it like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready")
    $(document).on("click", '#pageRight', move_up);
    $(document).on("click", '#pageLeft', move_down)
});
```

or:

```
$('#pageRight').click(move_up);
$('#pageLeft').click(move_down);
```

1st one will work even if buttons are created on runtime.

Comment: he wrote that he tried `.click()`. Why do you think this will work differently? The first format would only be necessary if the buttons are added dynamically.